# Getting no pods error while checking the logs of a pod even the pod is up and running

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-dashboard

I installed kubernetes dashboard by referring kubernetes.io, everything was fine (I edited the pod and replaced cluster-ip with Nodeport)

[image]

but the dashboard does not respond after some time of being logged in. Again I have to login using bearer token and again the cycle repeats after some time. when I checked the logs using `kubectl logs podname` it throws an error as no pods found by that name but if I pass kubectl get pods it shows as the pod is running and even I can able to access it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have namespacename using `-n` flag to the `kubectl logs` command. Without namespacename it looks for the pod in `default` namespace but your pod is in `kubernetes-dashboard` namespace.

```
kubectl logs podname -n kubernetes-dashboard
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply, i missed the -n namespace argument.

Answer (score 0):

you need to have namespace using *-n* flag.
Normally is ***-n kube-system*** .